# PyQt4 - how to disable all hot keys (native keyboard shortcuts)

Tags: python, pyqt4, hotkeys

I have a PyQt4 GUI that houses numerous libraries (such as Mayavi) which have their own internal keyboard shortcuts natively (already present without putting in any code to set them up). One such key is `s` in Mayavi - if you press this button while hovering over a Mayavi Figure, a save window will appear. Even worse, pressing the letter `p` while hovering over will completely freeze out all camera controls on that window.

I made a similar post back in April on how to turn off these shortcuts within one of these embedded libraries (Mayavi) - however, 5 months later and it appears such knowledge is very elusive.

Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**
I've edited the original post based on forum feedback - very sorry for obfuscating this issue; hopefully the below code will prove more clear:

```
import sys, os
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
from traits.api import HasTraits,Instance,on_trait_change,Int
from traitsui.api import View,Item,VGroup
from mayavi import mlab
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, MlabSceneModel, SceneEditor

class Mayavi_Scene(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_scene(self):
        Mayavi_Scene.fig1 = mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(.5,.5,.5))
        self.scene.mlab.clf(figure=Mayavi_Scene.fig1)
        testPlot = mlab.test_contour3d()

    view = View(Item('scene', editor = SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                    height=300, width=300, show_label=False),
                resizable=True,
                )

class P1(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P1, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        self.label_avgVol = QtGui.QLabel('PyQt window without Mayavi')
        self.label_avgVol.setMargin(5)
        self.label_avgVol.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Box | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.label_avgVol.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_avgVol, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.label_avgVol.show()

class P2(QtGui.QWidget):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(P2, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)

        self.label_edge1 = QtGui.QLabel('')
        self.label_edge1.setMargin(5)
        self.label_edge1.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Panel | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_edge1, 0, 0, 4, 3)
        self.label_edge1.show()

        self.label_avgVol = QtGui.QLabel('PyQt window with Mayavi')
        self.label_avgVol.setMargin(5)
        self.label_avgVol.setFrameStyle(QtGui.QFrame.Box | QtGui.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.label_avgVol.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        layout.addWidget(self.label_avgVol, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        self.label_avgVol.show()

        self.viz1 = Mayavi_Scene()
        self.ui1 = self.viz1.edit_traits(parent=self, kind='subpanel').control
        layout.addWidget(self.ui1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Test", self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.button.show()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        tab1 = P1(self)
        tab2 = P2(self)
        global tabs
        tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        tabs.addTab(tab1, 'eventFilter works')
        tabs.addTab(tab2, 'eventFilter ignored')
        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)
        self.show()

        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            print('KeyPress: %s [%r]' % (event.key(), source))
            return True
            #event.ignore()

        return super(MainWindow, self).eventFilter(source, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What shortcuts do you mean?

Comment: The first thing to do is [install an event-filter](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the application object and check that the relevant events can be intercepted.

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm not sure what the shortcuts actually are, but if I go through and press each key on my keyboard one by one, weird glitches occur. For example, while hovering over a Mayavi scene (on mac OS), the 'p' button completely freezes out all camera controls until the program is restarted.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you for the tip - I'll check into it and post back here with my findings.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've added an update above; if you have time, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @ees change `event.ignore()` to `return True`.

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for the delayed response! even though this change works when pressing a key while hovering over the PyQt exclusive window, the second that I hover over the Mayavi Figure window within PyQt and press a key, that key is NOT blocked. Are you getting something different on your end?

Comment: this method only works for Qt widgets, if the focus is on other widgets it can not be handled by Qt.

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the clarification; I'll update the above code now, and accept this as solved.

Comment: I have a too low reputation to comment but I just want to say that this thread helped me a great deal when dealing with an animation UI (anim picker) that I'm doing.
I wanted to block specific hotkeys (A and F) in Maya when the mouse cursor is over the UI so these hotkeys act on the UI only.
The 'eventFilter' trick you are using allowed me to listen to the keyboard without making the UI taking priority over Maya on everything as 'keyPressEvent' does.

Comment: if it's theme actual, i found solution in this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417640/prevent-tab-cycling-with-ctrltab-by-default-with-qtabwidget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: Thanks to the very helpful individuals in the comments, the above code (in the original post) works as it is supposed to (or as best it can). There is apparently no way to control events on modules held within PyQt (such as Mayavi) through the PyQt event filter. However, if anyone is looking for the correct layout to control PyQt events alone, it has been supplied here.